# Shopping basket creation what's missing?

Tags: c#

Hi I've been spending a while creating a shopping basket application in C# using Win-forms and well... I've hit a wall I guess. I've got 5 buttons (add to items / remove / clear all / save / exit) as well as 4 list boxes (item name / price / total number of items / total value) and a numeric up/down for Quantity. It compiles just fine So I guess I kinda have a list of things that I'm just lacking the mental capacity to implement or fix... 
1. my Add to items button doesn't actually add items to the list box it seems 
2. not really sure how to get my "quantity" box to correctly work (e.g item: Carrot  quantity: 2   price: 0.30) so the listbox would show "Carrot £0.60")
3. Total number of items (not sure if this works yet due to lb)(supposed to work like carrot, fridge, beef = 3 in total number of items)
4. Total Value (not sure if works due to others but is supposed to calculate items in basket and bring back the sum)

I think apart from these things everything else works... I'll provide my code in pastebin links as well as on here for ease of access

UI https://gyazo.com/4990c1e24f4705c53049eeacb7e9e720

OrderItems class  http://pastebin.com/yy5TTWAK

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ShoppingBasket
{
    public class OrderItems
    {
        // my get setters ctors
        public string ItemName { get; private set; }
        public int NumberOfStock { get; private set; }
        public decimal ReplacementValue { get; private set; }

        public OrderItems(string groceryName, int replacementValue)
        {
            this.ItemName = groceryName;
            this.NumberOfStock = replacementValue;
        }

        public OrderItems()
        {
        }

        public decimal TotalValueReplacer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.NumberOfStock * this.ReplacementValue;
            }
        }

        public int AddStock()
        {
            this.NumberOfStock++;
            return this.NumberOfStock;
        }

        //this adds stock
        public int AddStock(decimal ReplacementValue)
        {
            this.NumberOfStock++;
            this.ReplacementValue = ReplacementValue;
            return this.NumberOfStock;
        }

        //this an individual removal
        public int RemoveStock()
        {
            this.NumberOfStock--;

            //this stops stock going below
            if (this.NumberOfStock < 0)
            {
                this.NumberOfStock = 0;
            }
            return this.NumberOfStock;
        }

        //this removes everything
        public void RemoveAllStock()
        {
            this.NumberOfStock = 0;
        }

        public void Save(string items)
        {

            try
            {
                var filename = @"C:\\Users\\Barry\\Desktop\\receipt.txt";

                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                using (objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filename))
                {
                    objWriter.Write(items);
                    objWriter.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var message = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

QA Class http://pastebin.com/dwJwYWpM

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ShoppingBasket
{
    public class QA
    {
        public List<OrderItems> Oitems { get; set; }

        public int StockTotal
        {
            get
            {
                int stock = 0;
                foreach (OrderItems oi in Oitems)
                {
                    stock += oi.NumberOfStock;
                }
                return stock;
            }
        }

        public decimal FinalReplacementValue
        {
            get
            {
                decimal GroceryReplaceValue = 0.0m;
                foreach (OrderItems o in Oitems)
                {
                    GroceryReplaceValue += o.TotalValueReplacer;
                }
                return GroceryReplaceValue;
            }
        }



        public void AddItem(string groceryName, int ReplacementValue)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Oitems.Count; i++)
            {
                //is item already added
                if (Oitems[i].ItemName == groceryName)
                {
                    Oitems[i].AddStock(ReplacementValue);
                    return;
                }
            }

            //adds if already an item
            OrderItems oi = new OrderItems(groceryName, ReplacementValue);
            Oitems.Add(oi);
        }

        public void DropItem(string groceryName)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Oitems.Count; i++)
            {
                //is item already addded
                if (Oitems[i].ItemName == groceryName)
                {
                    Oitems[i].RemoveStock();
                    return;
                }
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("item {0} is invalid", groceryName));
        }

        public void RemoveItem(string groceryName)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Oitems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Oitems[i].ItemName == groceryName)
                {
                    Oitems.RemoveAt(i);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        public void RemoveAllItem()
        {
            Oitems.Clear();
        }

    }
}
```

Shopping window class http://pastebin.com/jmAgr9DG

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShoppingBasket
{
    public partial class ShoppingWindow : Form
    {

        private QA basket = new QA();

        public ShoppingWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void txtItemName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string itemName = txtItemName.Text;
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var items = "";
            foreach (var item in lbItems.SelectedItems)
            {
                items += item.ToString();
                items += "\n";
            }

            var order = new OrderItems();
            order.Save(items);

            MessageBox.Show("Receipt saved.");

        }

        private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lbItems.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                //item selected
                OrderItems oi = basket.Oitems[lbItems.SelectedIndex];
                basket.RemoveItem(oi.ItemName);
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            basket.RemoveAllItem();
            MessageBox.Show("All Items removed.");
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: `btnAdd_Click` - you're not actally adding anything....

Comment: okay.. I thought "string itemName = txtItemName.Text;" would be adding whatever was typed in that box